# Counterexample of Remmert's theorem without properness

Tags: algebraic-geometry, analytic-geometry, complex-geometry

The Remmert's proper mapping theorem states

> **Remmert's proper mapping theorem**: Let $f:X\to Y$ be a proper holomorphic map of complex spaces and $A\subset X$ a closed analytic subset. Then $f(A)$ is analytic in $Y$.

As mentioned in the answer of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/259634/proper-mapping-theorem), Remmert's proper mapping theorem is a consequence of Grauert's direct image theorem, which states:

> **Grauert's direct image theorem**: Let $f:X\to Y$ be a proper holomorphic map of complex spaces and $\mathcal{F}$ a coherent sheaf on $X$. Then all sheaves $R^qf_*(\mathcal{F})$ are coherent.

By Oka's coherence theorem, the structure sheaf $\mathcal{O}_A$ is a coherent $\mathcal{O}_X$-module. Consequently, $f_*(\mathcal{O}_A)$ is coherent as $\mathcal{O}_Y$-module, whose support is $f(A)$, showing $f(A)$ is analytic.

**I'd like to find an example when the analyticity fails without the assumption of properness.** Note it is not enough to find an example where Grauert's theorem fails, because without the properness assumption, $supp(f_*(\mathcal{F}))$ can be larger than $f(A)$, and a support of a non-coherent sheaf can still be analytic (Consider the embedding $\mathbb C^*\hookrightarrow \mathbb C$ and push forward of structure sheaf).

Therefore, it seems we should directly work on a counterexample of Remmert's. Consider the closure of the graph $z\mapsto \exp(\frac1z)$ inside $\mathbb C\times \mathbb C$. This space is not analytic because a general horizontal hyperplane section of this space is not finitely generated (a consequence of [Great Picard's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard_theorem)).

Now, let $Z$ denote the space stated above, and $Y=\mathbb C\times \mathbb C$. My question is that is it possible to find a pair of analytic spaces $A\subset X$, and holomorphic (non-proper) mapping $f:X\to Y$, such that $Z=f(A)$?