# Albanese map for complex compact manifold

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, hodge-theory

Let $X$ be a compact Kahler manifold. To it, it is possible to associate a complex torus $Alb(X)$ with a map $$alb: X \to Alb(X) .$$

In class, our teacher claimed the image of this map generates the whole torus, but I'm not able neither to prove this result nor to find it on our textbooks.

Comment: You can read Huybrechts'Complex Geometry Chapter 3.3Lefschetz Theorems p135.

Comment: In dimension one, this is essentially Jacobi inversion theorem. In higher dimensions it can be regarded as Jacobi inversion for codimension one cycles. See Voisin's _Hodge Theory and Complex Algebraic Geometry_, volumn I, Lemma 12.11 for the proof.

Comment: @AGlearner good pick on the reference! Would you care to submit that proof as an answer?

Comment: Thank you for the great reference! I still do not manage to completely understand the proof that Voisin presents there. In particular, why it is sufficient to show the map is a submersion at a point to get surjectivity

Comment: @TommasoScognamiglio It used [proper mapping theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/259634/proper-mapping-theorem/931102), therefore $alb^k(X^k)\subset Alb(X)$ is an analytic subvariety. If it contains an open ball, then it has to be the entire $Alb(X)$ by dimension reason.

Comment: oh thank you a lot !now everything is clearer !:)

Comment: Correction: I wrote "In higher dimensions... Jacobi inversion for codimension one cycles." It should be "dimension zero cycles". Sorry for the confusion. Actually Abel-Jacobi map for dimension-zero cycles $alb:CH_0(X)_{hom}\to Alb(X)$ is quite different from Abel-Jacobi for codimension-one cycles $\alpha: CH^{1}_{hom}(X)\to Pic^0(X)$. For example, $\alpha$ is always injective, while $alb$
can has large kernel (Mumford, 1968), even though both agree in $\dim(X)=1$ where Abel-Jacobi map is an isomorphism.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment, it is proved in Voisin's Hodge Theory and Complex Algebraic Geometry, Volumn I, Lemma 12.11. I will just paraphrase the proof here.

Let $k\ge 1$ and denote $X^k=X\times\cdots \times X$, the $k$-the Cartesian product. Let $alb^k$ be the map $$alb^k:X^k\to Alb(X):=H^0(X,\Omega^1)^*/H_1(X,\mathbb Z)$$ $$(x_1,...,x_k)\mapsto  (\omega\mapsto \sum_{i=1}^k\int_{x_0}^{x_i}\omega).$$

> **Theorem**: The map $alb^k:X^k\to Alb(X)$ is surjective for $k>>0$.

*Proof*: By [proper mapping theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/259634/proper-mapping-theorem/931102), it suffices to show that $alb^k$ is submersive at some point $\vec{x}=(x_1,...,x_k)$. Dualize the tangent map, it reduces to show injectivity between cotangent spaces

$$T^*_{alb^k(\vec{x})}Alb(X)\to T^*_{x_1}X\times\cdots \times T^*_{x_k}X.\tag{1}\label{1}$$
 at some point $alb^k(\vec{x})$. Since a torus $V/\Lambda$ has trivial (co)tagent bundle, the cotangent space at any of its point is canonically identified with $V^*$. Therefore, the LHS of $(\ref{1})$ is identified with $H^0(X,\Omega^1)$ and the map $(\ref{1})$ is just restriction. Now, it is clear that one can choose integer $k$ and points $x_1,...,x_k$ realizing the injectivity. $\square$

**Remark 1**: When $\dim X=1$, this is just *Jacobi inversion theorem* for compact Riemann surfaces. Moreover, $Alb(X)$ coincides with Jacobi variety $Jac(X)$ and one can choose $k=\text{genus}(X)$ to generate the torus. (See Griffiths & Harris p.237 for an elementary proof, *without* using proper mapping theorem.)

**Remark 2**: An alternative way to prove this theorem is to apply *universality property* of Albanese map $alb:X\to Alb(X)$, i.e., for any holomorphic map $f:X\to T$ to some complex torus with $f(x_0)=0$, there exists a unique morphism of complex tori $$g:Alb(X)\to T$$
such that $f=g\circ alb$.

On the other hand, one can show that the analytic subvariety generated by $alb(X)$ in $Alb(X)$ is a subtorus, which still satisfies the universal property. Now, uniqueness guarantees that it has to be the whole $Alb(X)$. (See Birkenhake-Lange's [Complex Abelian Varieties](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-3-662-06307-1), Prop. 11.11.8).

Comment: I am sorry, but your sentence "Now, it is clear that one can choose integer $k$
 and points $x_1,\dots,x_k$ realizing the injectivity" is not clear to me. How do you see this?

Comment: @DougLiu Pick a basis $\omega_1,\ldots,\omega_k$ for $H^0(X,\Omega_X^1)$. Choose points $x_1,\ldots, x_k$ such that $\omega_i$ doesn't vanish at $x_i$, then the injectivity is realized.

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot agree. The images of the members of the basis are nonzero, which does not give injectivity. Consider the linear map $k^2\to k$ by $(1,0)\mapsto 1,(0,1)\mapsto 1$.

Comment: @HaohaoLiu Pick w1 and then x1 such that w1 does not vanish at x1. Then pick w2 that vanishes at x1, and pick x2 where w2 does not vanish. Then pick w3 that vanishes at both x1 and x2, and x3 where w3 does not vanish, and so on. Inductively you have no form to pick after finite steps (at most the dimension of space of holomorphic one-forms), so done.

Comment: Thanks! This step is clear now. BTW, your last paragraph is imprecise. $alb(X)$ is an analytic subvariety of $Alb(X)$, which may not be the whole $Alb(X)$. But a high power does generate $Alb(X)$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A$ be the set of analytic maps from $X$ to a complex torus, for $h\in A,h:X\to \Bbb{C}^m/L$ then $dh(x)_i$ is an holomorphic one-form on $X$, let $V$ be the complex subspace of $\Omega_X$ generated by all those $dh(x)_i,h\in A$.

$\Omega_X$ thus $V$ is finite dimensional because $\pi_1(X,x_0)$ is finitely generated and if $\omega$ integrates to $0$ on every closed-loop then $\int_{x_0}^x \omega$ is holomorphic $X\to \Bbb{C}$ thus it attains its maximum modulus at some $x\in X$, thus it is constant and $\omega=0$.

Take a basis $V=\sum_{j=1}^d \omega_j \Bbb{C}$, fix some $x_0\in X$, let $\Lambda = \{ (\int_\gamma\omega_1,\ldots,\int_\gamma \omega_d)\in \Bbb{C}^d,\gamma \in \pi_1(X,x_0)\}$ then $$Alb(X)=\Bbb{C}^d/\Lambda, \qquad F: X\to Alb(X),\qquad F(x)=(\int_{x_0}^x\omega_1,\ldots,\int_{x_0}^x\omega_d)$$
$\Lambda$ is a discrete subgroup of $\Bbb{C}^d$ because any $h\in A,h:X\to \Bbb{C}^m/L$ factors as $h=h(x_0)+H\circ F+L$ with $H$ linear $\Bbb{C}^d\to \Bbb{C}^m$ (where $H(y)_i=\sum_j c_{ij} y_j, dh(x)_i = \sum_j c_{ij}\omega_j$) and with enough different $h$ the obtained $H$ is injective. $\Bbb{R}\Lambda=\Bbb{C}^d$ for the same reason.

Thus $\Lambda$ is a lattice and $Alb(X)$ is a complex torus.

Every $h\in A$ factors uniquely through $F$. By a dimensionality argument (the image of $\mathrm{x}\in X^d \to \sum_{k=1}^d F(\mathrm{x}_k)\in Alb(X)$ contains  a $d$-dimensional complex ball) any point of $Alb(X)$ is a $\Bbb{Z}$-linear combination of some $F(\mathrm{x}_k)$.

Comment: Sorry I did not understand the last phrase , which should address precisely my doubt.

Comment: Cover $X$ by finitely many charts $\phi_i$, for each chart it makes sense to talk about $\partial_{z_j} F\circ \phi_i(z)\in \Bbb{C}^d$, then the set of all those $\partial_{x_j} F\circ \phi_i(z)$ contains a $\Bbb{C}$-basis $\partial_{x_{j_k}} F\circ \phi_{i_k}(z_k)$ of $\Bbb{C}^d$ (because otherwise $\Lambda$ would be contained in a subspace of $\Bbb{C}^d$), then the image of $\mathrm{x}\to\sum_k F(\mathrm{x}_k)$ (for $\mathrm{x}_k$ close to $\phi_{i_k}(z_k)$)  contains an open ball of $Alb(X)$, the shifts of this open ball cover $Alb(X)$

Comment: Sorry still can't understand your proof. Why the image must contain a $\mathbb{C}$ basis?